# How to Use Groovy code as an AWS SQS Listener

Tags: grails, groovy, amazon-sqs

I have been Googling trying to find Groovy code to act as a long running process as an AWS SQS Listener to receive  messages from a SQS Queue. I see Spring Boot & Grails but I cannot seem to find any Groovy code.
Trying to reduce dependencies. I have used Java code in Groovy many years back-might fall back to that if nothing else is available.

TIA

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: Trying to see if there is some long running Groovy process code acting as a SQS Listener. I have done this with nodes but they have standard AWS SQS library for that.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/getting-started.html

Comment: Did you solve this or do you still need help?

Comment: I was able to use Spring Boot with embedded Tomcat as an SQS Listener.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use Spring Boot with embedded Tomcat as an SQS Listener using this example - https://www.netsurfingzone.com/aws/spring-boot-aws-sqs-listener-example/